# Failing to fully uninstall node@8 and reinstall latest node

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I had node@8 installed through brew.
I decided to upgrade and uninstalled `node@8`.

Did `brew doctor`, `brew cleanup` -> all nice and clean.

If I now run `node -v`

I am getting this:

```
-bash: /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

Which is fine(-ish).

Reinstalled latest node through brew. It complained about failing to run postinstallation. And didn't link the newly installed node.

So, now if I try to run node I still get the same error.

Tried relinking:

```
brew link node
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/node/12.3.1
To relink: brew unlink node && brew link node
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Try to force the re-linkage `brew link --overwrite --force node@12.3`

Comment: Use of Node Version Manager (nvm)? There you can switch, download, ... different node version